# problem with sending token

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, tokens

I always having issue with sending token. when I send token even transaction get confirm, the token remain in my wallet and I lost only ether on fees!
what wrong with ethereum!

Comment: Can you add more details, like the Solidity code for the token, how you are sending the transaction, and whether you're using testrpc or a live test chain?

Answer (score 1):

There might be Many reasons. One of them is using error handling patterns.

```
1.assert()
2.require()
3.return()
4.revert()

When there is throw while executing the contract, the gas used while executing, will loss. It means while executing , fee takes will and will not be recovered. 

Make sure that which handling method will be appropriate for that specific purpose .
```

Fur further information : https://medium.com/blockchannel/the-use-of-revert-assert-and-require-in-solidity-and-the-new-revert-opcode-in-the-evm-1a3a7990e06e